# Clearing text_area on edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

As the title says, i need when a user presses "edit" button on my Ticket model, the text_area field get empty and not show any current info that it pulls from the database. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this in the controller.
Supposing your text_field is named `my_field`

```
def edit
    @ticket.my_field=nil
end
```

This way, it will render empty on the view.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most expedient thing to do here is to have your controller pass `@ticket` with the attribute's value cleared. Something like:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    @ticket.note_text = ""
  end
end
```